# Real value of equation $(x-\frac{1}{x})^\frac{1}{2}+(1-\frac{1}{x})^\frac{1}{2}=x$

Tags: polynomials

Find the real value of x in the equation $(x-\frac{1}{x})^\frac{1}{2}+(1-\frac{1}{x})^\frac{1}{2}=x$

I tried to square the whole term and after expansion not getting the result.

Comment: Can you show what you got after squaring and expanding?

Comment: $x^3=x^2+x-2+(x-1)(x+1)^\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: After this it is getting complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note for the expression $(1-1/x)^{1/2}$ to have meaning, $1$ must be greater than or equal to $1/x$. So $x\geq1$.

Squaring both sides, $$x-\frac{1}{x}+2\left(x-1-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{1/2}+1-\frac{1}{x}=x^2$$

Rearranging:
$$2\left(x-1-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{1/2}=x^2-x-1+\frac{2}{x}$$

Squaring again:
$$4\left(x-1-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=x^4-2x^3-x^2+6x-3-\frac{4}{x}+\frac{4}{x^2}$$
$$0=x^4-2x^3-x^2+2x+1$$
$$0=\left(x^2-x-1\right)^2$$
$$0=x^2-x-1$$

There is one solution greater than $1$, the large Golden Ratio, $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\approx1.613\ldots$.

Answer (score 2):

We may assume $x>0$. From $\sqrt{x^2-1}+\sqrt{x-1}=x\sqrt{x}$, subtract $\sqrt{x-1}$ from both side and squaring gives us $$x^2-1=x^3+x-1-2x\sqrt{x^2-x}$$
Simplifying, $$(x^2-x)-2\sqrt{x^2-x}+1=0$$
Can you go on from here?

Comment: I was typing the same when your answer came ! You are too fast for the old man. By the way $+1$.

Answer (score 0):

$(x-1/x)=(x-(1-1/x)^{1/2}) ^{2}
\leftrightarrow x=x^{2}+1-2x(1-1/x)^{1/2}
\leftrightarrow (x^{2}-x+1)^{2}=4x^{2}(1-1/x)
$

Comment: $x\ne 0$ is a condition

Comment: Then the other solution can also be derived from the 2nd equation. You need to somehow get rid of square root parts to solve this equation. If x=0 is not a solution the taking out x as a common part the rest expression equals to zero

Comment: I am not sure that this is correct. Solve it and you will get $\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{17}\right)$ which is not the answer. Hazve a look at @cortek's answer.

Comment: I checked it... I missed a part... Now i think it's ok